# Scala [Functional]: Find the actual indices of an element within a list that may be repeated

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to write a method that gets a  list of characters, and returns a list that each element of it will be a (indexOfelement, element) tuple.

As you know, we can use the `indexOf`, as following:

```
def buggyAttempt (charsList: List[Char]): List[(Int, Char)] = charsList.map(char => (charsList.indexOf(char), char))
```

This works fine if there is no repetition within the elements. So the question is, how to deal with the a list of repeated characters? For example if I feed it `List("a", "b", "c", "c")`, I will get `List((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,c))`.

I want to solve this problem in a functional manner, so no mutable variables.

Comment: Maybe a typo but I think you mean `List((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,c))`

Comment: So what exactly do you want, a list of lists or distinct elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here is the version of your code that compiles:

```
def notBuggyAttempt (charsList: List[Char]): List[(Int, Char)] = { 
    charsList.map(char => (charsList.indexOf(char), char))
}
```

This will return the tuples with only the first indices.

To obtain what you want, though, you may use zipWIthIndex, which returns List[(Char, Int)], then, if you want a List[(Int, Char)], you have to swap the elements:

```
def getIndexTuples (charsList: List[Char]): List[(Int, Char)] = {
    charsList.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
}
```

Comment: Using IndexOf() makes multiple parsings on the list. If the list is very large there will be significant performance overheads.

Comment: My proposed solution does not make use of `indexOf`, I just rewrote the code of the answer in a way that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your input is

```
val input = List('a','b','c','c')
```

you can get the output using

```
input.zipWithIndex.collect{
  case (t1,t2) => (t2,t1)
}
```

Output will be

```
res0: List[(Int, Char)] = List((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zipWithIndex` with `map`   as below:

```
x.zipWithIndex.map(v=>(v._2,v._1))
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> val x = List("a", "b", "c", "c")
x: List[String] = List(a, b, c, c)

scala> x.zipWithIndex.map(v=>(v._2,v._1))
res22: List[(Int, String)] = List((0,a), (1,b), (2,c), (3,c))
```

Using IndexOf() makes multiple parsings on the list. If the list is very large there will be significant performance overheads.